# Spring ignores permitAll rule

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following WebSecurity configuration:

```
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationAuthenticationProvider appProvider;
        
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("apiAuthenticationFilter")
        public TokenAuthenticationFilter apiAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler,
                TokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler) throws Exception {
            TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
            filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
            return filter;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/oauth2/token", "/api/oauth2/application/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/internal**").hasAuthority("READ_ALL")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(apiAuthenticationFilter(null, null), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(this.appProvider)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
                .and()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout().disable();
        }
```

I tried accessing `http://localhost:8080/api/oauth2/token?client_id=...&other_query_params=param`, but instead of accessing that page, like configured here:

```
                .antMatchers("/oauth2/token", "/oauth2/application/token").permitAll()
```

It calls the filter chain and the filter added here:

```
                .addFilterBefore(apiAuthenticationFilter(null, null), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

which rejects my request cause of a missing token, but it should be allowed instead.

That is what my log says:

```
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/oauth2/token'; against '/api/**'
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/oauth2/token?client_id=123&client_secret=secret&code=code&grant_type=authorization_code at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/oauth2/token?client_id=123&client_secret=secret&code=code&grant_type=authorization_code at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/oauth2/token?client_id=123&client_secret=secret&code=code&grant_type=authorization_code at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/oauth2/token?client_id=123&client_secret=secret&code=code&grant_type=authorization_code at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'TokenAuthenticationFilter'
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/oauth2/token'; against '/api/**'
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] d.t.o.a.a.TokenAuthenticationFilter      : Request is to process authentication
26-01-2021  INFO 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] d.t.o.a.a.TokenAuthenticationFilter      : Invoked attempAuthentication
26-01-2021 DEBUG 17744 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] d.t.o.a.a.TokenAuthenticationFilter      : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Invalid token submitted: null
```

Comment: shouldn't `"/oauth2/token", "/oauth2/application/token"` be `"/api/oauth2/token", "/api/oauth2/application/token"`?

Comment: @Lino Yes, it was before, but then it also does not work

Comment: i think, .anyRequest().authenticated() overrides your permitAll() url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the bug right now, it was a logical mistake. I want to explain what the problem was.

Since I wanted to use oauth2 authentication in my application, I added a filter called `TokenAuthenticationFilter` to get the `Authorization` Header and authenticate using the credentials in that header. But my filter did not limit the cases where to apply. So all requests, also the "permitAll" requests were going through that filter and rejected cause of no authentication. So I changed my code that the filter only applies if the "Authorization" Header is set and now everything works.